# Azure Branch policy on PR to "sub master"

Tags: azure-devops, branch, pull-request

We have a Master branch and a 'sub master branch'(for development on a side project) lets call them A and B (sub) for easier understanding. B is every ~12 hour updated with new merges that comes into A.

Would it be posible to set up some sort of policy on B, so that if a new branch is created off B, when we make a pull request, it automatically chooses B as target to merge into instead of A (Master / Default). The policy still needs to allow branches off A to merge into A.

This way our team can work on A and B at the same time, but avoid merging a PR into the wrong target, yes i know you can choose the target branch to merge into manually when creating the PR, but i also know that we are humans and this is where mistakes happend (already happend to me and i was saved by a merge conflict).

We have searched everywhere reading docummentation about this, but come up empty handed, maybe we are simply looking for the wrong keywords / searches, who knows, but any feedback would be greatly apriciated.

*update* is this similar to having master and dev branch (ours is called XD_master), though we dont merge from XD_master into Master untill the product is done, untill then we only rebase to keep XD_master up to date with master.

Comment: "Would it be posible to set up some sort of policy on B..." I'm pretty sure the answer is "It's probably possible to set something up." But it wouldn't be anything out of the box, and it's not guaranteed that it would always detect the starting branch with 100% accuracy (because the concept of "parent branch" doesn't exist in Git outside of looking at the history and making educated guesses).

Comment: To clarify, "B is every ~12 hour updated with new merges that comes into A." You do that by automatically rebasing? (As mentioned in the last sentence.) I don't think the fact that you're rebasing is relevant to your question, but each time you rebase you're (probably) losing all of the PR merge commits. Maybe you're OK with that, but in my experience having those merge commits is useful, especially when wishing to determine which commits were related to which PR, and having access to the code review comments.

Comment: On further thought, the fact that you're rebasing to update `XD_master` probably *is* relevant to the solution you can choose to achieve your goal. One solution that comes to mind is to look at the history of the new branch, and see if it contains commits already on `XD_master` that aren't on `master`. If there are some, then we can assume the target branch should be `XD_master`. But if the commits in the history of the new branch get rebased after the branch is created, and before the PR is created, then no commits would match that criteria.

Comment: Just want to update, we went with manually merging instead as our pipeline had to undergo too many changes for this to work.